Random, Flutter: Lost connection to device
I am developing a flutter desktop application in a new windows's machine on vscode IDE, on acer's NitorV
Scenario 1: While working after 10-15 minutes console reads: Lost connection to device but the flutter application is still running [i had uploaded the image of same].Scenario 1
Scenario 2: When i close the application running and restart by flutter run, the error "LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open" comes up and i have to use flutter clean and rebuild the app by flutter run.Scenario 2
i can confirm that i have plenty of storage.
i ran flutter doctor command and the results are file, there are 3 issues but that relates to absence of android studios, as i am developing desktop app i didn't installed the android studios. Flutter doctor
I was developing same application on my previous laptop and never faced this issue but now i am unable to focus on work because the application randomly closes.
Please share your valuable insights.
